# Vite asset paths on Github Pages behaving differently

Tags: github-pages, vite

I've got a Vite project I'm publishing to ghpages where I need to play some audio files.

The paths to the audio files come in two flavours - one hardcoded, one not.

```
const bgUrl = new URL("/audio/backgroundAudio.wav", import.meta.url).href;
// Do something with bgUrl

const fileName = `/audio/${event.name}.wav`;
const sfxUrl = new URL(fileName, import.meta.url).href;
// Do something with sfxUrl
```

The hardcoded path resolves correctly on ghpages, adding the repo name as the base so the request goes through.
The second path which is built on the fly with event data never adds the base correctly and so the request 404s.

I have the repo name set correctly, under the `base` property in the vite config.

**Why would a hardcoded url work and the other fail?**

Bonus question - I'm using the new URL(...) because that's the only way I found to get assets to work at all on ghpages. If I'm doing something wrong here please let me know!